# How to integrate $\int^1_{-1}\frac{\pi}2 e^{ix}\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\text{ d}x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions

I have an integral I need to integrate, as follows
$$\int^1_{-1}\frac{\pi}2 e^{ix}\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\text{ d}x$$
This is quite troublesome to do, since I cannot use rectangular contour to contour integrate due to the bounds, and rewriting into exponential form didn't help.

Wolfram alpha spits out a hypergeometric antiderivative, and it seems like the only way to express this in any remotely closed form. Is there a way to derive the hypergeometric expression of the integral? (perhaps through finding the antiderivative or something?)

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, only $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{\cosh(bx)}dx$ has a nice form. With your bounds, why not start by looking at the definitions of hypergeometrics and working towards them with your integral.

Comment: For some reason, this integral looks like it equals a real number even though there is that $e^{ix}$. That number approximates to 2.037215546.

Comment: @Accelerator that is because the imaginary part is odd! And hence cancels out :P

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I didn't think about that for some reason. @CaptainChicky

Comment: What is amazing is that a short series solution gives a very decent result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will prove the integral in question equals

$$\frac{2\pi}{\pi+2i}\left(e^{\pi/2+i}\text{ }_2F_1\left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{\pi}\right) - e^{-\pi/2-i}\text{ }_2F_1\left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{-\pi}\right)\right).$$

To do this, we will enforce the [Hypergeometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}$, which equals

$$_2F_1 \left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right) - \frac{2\pi}{3\pi+2i}e^{2x} \text{ }_2F_1 \left(2, \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{5}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right),$$

and apply the known result

$$\frac{d}{dz} \text{ } _2F_1 (a,b;c;f(z)) = \frac{ab}{c}\text{ } _2F_1 (a+1,b+1;c+1;f(z))f'(z).$$

**Proof.** Let the integral be $I$. Then using $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}x \mapsto x$ yields

$$
\eqalign{
I =& \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{2ix/\pi}\operatorname{sech}\left(x\right)dx \cr
=& \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2e^x e^{2ix/\pi}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}\right)dx \cr
=& \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2e^x e^{2ix/\pi}\bigg(\text{ }_2F_1 \left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right) \cr
&- \frac{2\pi}{3\pi+2i}e^{2x} \text{ }_2F_1 \left(2, \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{5}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right)\bigg)dx \cr
=& \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2e^{2x}e^{2ix/\pi}\text{ }_2F_1 \left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right)dx \cr
&- \frac{4\pi}{3\pi + 2i}e^{3x}e^{2ix/\pi}\text{ }_2F_1 \left(2, \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{5}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right)dx.
} 
$$
We use integration by parts through
$$
\eqalign{
u &= \text{ }_2F_1 \left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right) \cr
\implies du &= -\frac{2\pi + 4i}{3\pi + 2i}e^{2x} \text{ }_2F_1 \left(2, \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{5}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right)
}
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
dv &=  2e^x e^{2ix/\pi}dx \cr
\implies v &= \frac{2\pi}{\pi+2i}e^{x}e^{2ix/\pi}. \cr
}
$$

Then

$$
\eqalign{
I =& \Bigg[\frac{2\pi}{\pi+2i}e^x e^{2ix/\pi} \text{ }_2F_1 \left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right) \Bigg]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cr
&- \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}-\frac{2\pi}{\pi+2i}e^x e^{2ix/\pi} e^{2x}\frac{2\pi + 4i}{3\pi + 2i}\text{ }_2F_1\left(2, \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{5}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right)dx \cr
&- \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{4\pi}{3\pi+2i}e^{3x}e^{2ix/\pi} \text{ }_2F_1\left(2, \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{5}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right)dx \cr
=& \Bigg[\frac{2\pi}{\pi+2i}e^x e^{2ix/\pi} \text{ }_2F_1 \left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{2x}\right) \Bigg]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cr
=& \frac{2\pi}{\pi+2i}\bigg(e^{\pi/2+i}\text{ }_2F_1\left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{\pi}\right) \cr
&- e^{-\pi/2-i}\text{ }_2F_1\left(1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi}; \frac{3}{2} + \frac{i}{\pi}; -e^{-\pi}\right)\bigg) \cr
}
$$
as desired!
**Q.E.D.**

Comment: Quick question - where did you get the hypergeometric series for 1/(1+e^(2x))? Is this in a table somewhere or did you derive it?

Comment: I differentiated the answer of $\int e^{2ix/\pi}\operatorname{sech}(x)$. Then after doing some algebra, I was thinking that $\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}$ equals that hypergeometric series you're talking about. I don't know how to derive that, though. I have tested the equality for multiple values of $x$ and it seems to hold true numerically, so it is more of a conjecture than anything, but I'm fairly certain it holds. @Max0815

Answer (score 3):

Because of the symmetry
$$I=\frac{\pi}2\int^{+1}_{-1} e^{ix}\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\text{ d}x=\pi \int_0^1\cos(x)\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\text{ d}x$$ I do not think that you can avoid the Gaussian hypergeometric function (even if it is one of the simplest).

Expanding the complex numbers,
$$\color{blue}{I=-\frac{2 e \pi }{1+e^2}+\frac{2 e^{\pi /2} \pi   (2 \sin (1)+\pi  \cos (1))}{4+\pi
   ^2}\,(H_1+H_2)-}$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac{2 e^{\pi /2} \pi  (\pi  \sin (1)-2 \cos (1))}{4+\pi ^2}\,(H_1-H_2)\, \color{red}{\large i}}$$ where

$$H_1=\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{\pi };\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{\pi};-e^{\pi }\right)$$
$$H_2=\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi };\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{\pi};-e^{\pi }\right)$$

$(H_1+H_2)$ is a real number
$$H_1+H_2=0.419817581157418905902747916112\cdots$$ and $(H_1-H_2)$ is an imaginary  number
$$H_1-H_2=0.287876065036803717328869876227\cdots i$$

None of them is recognized by inverse symbolic alculators even in terms of special functions.

Comment: I’m curious how you derived the blue expression  I tried manipulating the integral into some hypergeometric form from a table of hypergeometric definitions I have but could not manage to do so. Please enlighten me xD

Comment: @CaptainChicky. I took the expression from WA and I transformed as much as I could the complex numbers. That's all. Cheers :-)